# How do i open DrawerNavigator upon clicking Bottom Tab Navigator in React-Navigation?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I'm using `react-navigation` and trying to open the drawer (with DrawerNavigator) upon clicking tab item in the `BottomTabNavigator`.

My current code looks like this

```
export default createBottomTabNavigator({
  Dashboard:{
      screen:Dashboard,
      navigationOptions:{
        tabBarLabel:'Dashboard',
        tabBarIcon:({tintColor}) => (
          <Icon name ="ios-speedometer-outline" color =
            {tintColor} size = {24} />
        )
      }
  },
  Customers:{
    screen:Customers,
    navigationOptions:{
      tabBarLabel:'Customers',
      tabBarIcon:({tintColor}) => (
        <Icon name ="ios-people-outline" color =
          {tintColor} size = {24} />
      )
    }
  },
  Invoice:{
    screen:Invoice,
    navigationOptions:{
      tabBarLabel:'Invoice',
      tabBarIcon:({tintColor}) => (
        <Icon name ="ios-copy-outline" color =
          {tintColor} size = {24} />
      )
    }
  },
  TimeTracker:{
    screen:TimeTracker,
    navigationOptions:{
      tabBarLabel:'Timetracker',
      tabBarIcon:({tintColor}) => (
        <Icon name ="ios-timer-outline" color =
          {tintColor} size = {24} />
      )
    }
  },
  More:{
   screen : More,

    navigationOptions:{
      tabBarLabel:'More',
      tabBarIcon:({tintColor}) => (
        <Icon name ="ios-menu-outline" color = {tintColor} size = {24} />
      )
    }
  }
},{
  tabBarOptions:{
    activeTintColor: 'red',
    inactiveTintColor: 'grey',
    style:{
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      borderTopWidth : 0,
      shadowOffset: {width:5,height : 3},
      shadowColor: 'black',
      shadowOpacity: 0.5,
      elevation: 5
    }
  }
})

const MyApp = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home :{
    screen : HomeScreen
  },
  Settings: {
    screen:SettingScreen
  }
})
```

I want to open drawerNavigator on the click of bottomTabNavigator. i.e, whenever More tab is pressed drawerNavigator get open.

How can I do this ?

I am new to the React-Native.

Answer (score 0):

you can use tabBarOnPress event in navigation options to modify tab navigation click

eg.

```
tabBarOnPress: (tab) => {
        //your code and other stuff 
        tab.jumpToIndex(tab.scene.index)
 }
```

Comment: Bro, i am not able to open drawer navigation.